# How to speed up heavy images website?

Tags: jquery

http://www.wacom.com/ this website is too fast although it has too many images of high resolution.

I have used pronto js in my websit http://www.benplum.com/projects/pronto/

Comment: They use an amazon service for static content. It might be a CDN: http://aws.amazon.com/de/cloudfront/

Answer (score 0):

Try `JQuery Lazy Load` library:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: I have all images in background i am not able to use lazyload

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best resource for learning more about optimizing the load speed of your website is Google Page Speed, which also has great many tools to diagnose and suggest improvements to your site if it is already online:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

As @strauberry mentioned, the Amazon Cloudfront CDN is probably a great contributor with assets being cached close to the user. Here is an English link:
http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

If you are using large background images, you can lazyload them with this: https://github.com/nordhagen/jquery-zload

In addition to @ra_hital's tip about jQuery Lazy Load for img elements.
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Hi-res images doesn't mean heavy images (On Wacom.com, images are less than 100Ko)
2. Configuring the Webserver you can return a header Connection: Keep-Alive to reduce the connect/disconnect time loss on every connection, suitable if you really have a lot of images to load (Note that this could at the contrary slowdown the whole thing if misused). Wacom website uses this.
3. If you load small images, it's better to create a single one and use CSS to display only part of them.